# Java HTTPPost Request with Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, http-headers, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need a java program to generate the following request.
I am using Apache HttpClient Library but still not able to produce a request like this:

This is what my python program generates and i wrote an equivalent java program. but its throwing 403.

2012-09-10 15:12:05G INFO: G2OAuth auth data = "3, 0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0, 1347289925, 3223833979, crlakamai"
2012-09-10 15:12:05G INFO: G2OAuth sign string = "3, 0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0, 1347289925, 3223833979, akamai/182228\nx-akamai-acs-action:version=1&action=dir&format=xml\n"

```
   send: 'POST /182228 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: crl.api.akamailab.com\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nX-Akamai-ACS-Auth-Data: 3, 0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0, 1347289925, 3223833979, crlsymc\r\nX-Akamai-ACS-Auth-Sign: eFnWtJBIyj4rxV3V0axF3w==\r\nX-Akamai-ACS-Action: version=1&action=dir&format=xml\r\n\r\n'

reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Server: Apache
header: Content-Type: text/html
header: Date: Mon, 10 Sep 2012 15:12:09 GMT
header: Content-Length: 31
header: Connection: keep-alive
```

The response looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<stat directory="/182232">
        <file type="file" name="log4j.properties" mtime="1346780907" size="301" md5="c92268157f1732a05c2027d151fc539a"/>
</stat>
```

Here is My Java Code:

```
    final HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("a.host.com", 80, "http");
    final DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    final Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user","pass");
    httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(targetHost.getHostName(), targetHost.getPort()), credentials);


    final HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost("akamai/182232");

    //Add your Data
    final List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(6);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Host: ", "a.host.com");
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Accept-Encoding: ", "identity"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Content-Length: ", "6"));

    httpPostRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    final HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(targetHost, httpPostRequest);

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }
```

My response looks like this.

```
2012-09-10 11:31:22,600 DEBUG [wire] >> "POST /182228/a.crl HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2012-09-10 11:31:22,601 DEBUG [wire] >> "Content-Length: 394[\r][\n]"
2012-09-10 11:31:22,601 DEBUG [wire] >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1[\r][\n]"
2012-09-10 11:31:22,601 DEBUG [wire] >> "Host: crl.api.symclab.com:80[\r][\n]"
2012-09-10 11:31:22,601 DEBUG [wire] >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2012-09-10 11:31:22,601 DEBUG [wire] >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.3 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
2012-09-10 11:31:22,602 DEBUG [wire] >> "[\r][\n]"
```

I want Accept-Encoding another headers as part of post, how do i add them ? It hast to be part of the post request i believe and not http header.

Answer (score 8):

Accept-Encoding is part of the HTTP Header, in addition to the parameters that you mistakenly sent as POST parameters:

Here is how to send it using HTTP Client:

```
httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-Length", "6"); 
httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "identity"); 
httpPostRequest.setHeader("Host", "a.host.com");
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to change the Http Header Accept-Encoding, you chang like this

```
httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
```

Your codes

```
final List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(6);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Host: ", "a.host.com");
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Accept-Encoding: ", "identity"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Content-Length: ", "6"));

httpPostRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

are used to send the value pairs in the http request body, **NOT IN THE HEADER**