# How to httpPost() to covert httpGet()?

Tags: android, json, http, http-post, http-get

The httpPost() java class here,

```
public String getXmlFromUrl_NewRegistration(String url,
        String username, String firstname, String lastname, String email,
        String password) {
    String json = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://aleedex.biz/game/users.php?action=new");
        String postParameter = "username=" + username + "&firstname="
                + firstname + "&lastname=" + lastname + "&email=" + email
                + "&password=" + password;

        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(postParameter));
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        json = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

        json = null;
    }

    Log.d("json", json);


    return json;
}
```

Also use same parameters in httpGet(), like username, firstname, lastname, email, password
how to register the user through httpGet() with same parameters on that link `http://aleedex.biz/game/users.php?action=new`

Comment: Maybe it is bad practice, but you can put all this information in the Http Header, and encrypt the connection using either SSL or TLS.

Comment: how cant it put information in http header any example

Comment: I used google for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358045/java-httppost-request-with-apache-httpclient

Comment: Thanks for that you struggle for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have follow that Tutorial and solve my problem [How to connect Android with PHP, MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

here you can append the post parameters to the url and then make a call it works that it

```
`HttpGet _getrequest=new HttpGet("http://aleedex.biz/game/users.php? action=new&"+postParameter); 

 HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(_getrequest);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    json = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);`
```

Try this i think this should work.

Comment: that is not helpful for me

Comment: What u want exactly u want the HttpGet request

Comment: yes, same parameters simply httppost change to httpget how i do it?