# How to send token as a header and id as a parameter in Http Post request?

Tags: android, http-post

```
   public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
    JSONObject jArray = null;
    String idTosend;
    String _accessToken = "saasfcsaas"

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(url);
    StringEntity se = null;     

    try {
        se = new StringEntity(_accessToken);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }

    httpPostRequest.addHeader("X-Auth-Token", _accessToken);

    httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);

    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Id",idTosend));

        httpPostRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        response = httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


  Here I am sending token as a header and Id as a parameter.
```

The above code is running but without the header.The fields which required the header to displays are returning null.

Please let me know what is wrong in the code.

Comment: afaik the method is called `setHeader` rather than `addHeader`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358045/java-httppost-request-with-apache-httpclient

Comment: you can use volley lib for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
    URL url;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("");
    try {
        url = new URL("URL");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        conn.setRequestProperty("X-Auth-Token", _accessToken);

        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Id",idTosend));

        writer.write(getQuery(params));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();

        conn.connect();

        STATUS = conn.getResponseCode();

        if(STATUS == 200 || STATUS == 201)
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        else
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "");
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "response: " + sb.toString());

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws     UnsupportedEncodingException{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for (NameValuePair pair : params)
    {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

---

For the best practice, try to use the [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: ok will try this and also Retrofit.thanks.Will let u know if get any errors.